# Android streaming data to server large latencies

Tags: android

I'm sending requests from my android phone one at a time as fast as possible to my server, and then graphing the time (x axis) vs hit number (starting at 0). After running this on Andrid for about 10 minutes, I get a graph like this:

[image]

The flat parts are unexpected. This signifies that every 3 minutes or so, there's a 1 minute lag that happens. Why might this be happening?

A few things I've noticed:

- It doesn't matter if the screen is on or off
- My server is not the problem. During the long pauses, I'm able to hit the endpoint on my server separately from android.
- Both POST requests and requests over websockets have the same problem
- It is possible the problem is my android data connection; I'm not sure how to remove this as a possible variable. It would be odd that the data connection would do this.

Comment: what about using emulator? maybe the problem because of your ISP

Comment: WiFi or cellular data connection? Either way, see if any logcat entries correlate with the lag events, for instance, changes in data service.

Comment: This graph is made on the server side i suppose. You should make such a graph too on the client side. You did not tell how you do your POST requests. One after another? And waiting for the server response first?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Looking into it, I think the issues do not stem from the data connection. The way I was able to tell was writing a similar script in javascript that sends continuous requests to the server, one after the other. Running this, I noticed that there were no flat spots while the phone was on (but there was an indefinite flat spot after about 5 minutes of standby.. I believe that's chrome deciding to stop running). An emulator is a great idea.

Comment: @greenapps The POST requests are one after the other, waiting for the server to respond first. I'm able to notice from logcat that the client side has the same "random pausing" issue.

Comment: You should be able to see from the logs why the client is pausing. Is it waiting for a server response or waiting for a connection being made. In both cases i would expect a time out. So where is that minute? What is the client doing then?

Comment: I've found an alternate solution. I'm sending requests to a Meteor app, and when I use DDP to send the requests I don't see any timeouts. I'm using this library: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP.